# How to iterate objects in Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have such a json file. My code below doesn't work. How to iterate "name" in Handlebars?

```
 { "test": [ { "33": { "name": "Prova 1", "surname": "Federico" } }, { "34": { "name": "Prova 2", "surname": "Antonio " } }, { "35": { "name": "Prova 3", "surname": "Giovanni" } } ] }
```

```html
 <div>
    {{debug}}
{{#each test}}
    
  <ul>
   <li>{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a double iterating one on test the second on the object in the array to get all properties (I use {{this}} because the name change every time) because name is nested in another object :

```
{{#each test}}
  <ul>
   <li>{{#each this}}{{name}}{{/each}}</li>
  </ul>
 {{/each}}
```

If you wanted to make work the code you've given you had to have such a json :

```
{ "test": [ 
{ "name": "Prova 1", "surname": "Federico" }, 
{ "name": "Prova 2", "surname": "Antonio " }, 
{ "name": "Prova 3", "surname": "Giovanni" } 
] }
```

You can check the snippet below that will demonstrate it with your data:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var context = {
    "test": [{
        "33": {
          "name": "Prova 1",
          "surname": "Federico"
        }
      },
      {
        "34": {
          "name": "Prova 2",
          "surname": "Antonio "
        }
      },
      {
        "35": {
          "name": "Prova 3",
          "surname": "Giovanni"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  var source = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
{{#each test}}
  <ul>
   <li>{{#each this}}{{name}}{{/each}}</li>
  </ul>
 {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Comment: If is it like that? var context = {
    "test": [
    {
        "33": [
        {
          "name": "Prova 1",
          "surname": "Federico"
      }
      ]
    },
      {
        "34": [
        {
          "name": "Prova 1",
          "surname": "Federico"
      }
      ]
    },
     { "34": [
        {
          "name": "Prova 1",
          "surname": "Federico"
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

Comment: Your solution work very well, thanks! But if json data is in external file?

Comment: Then you have to write something that will get your json first before submitting it to the handlebar template.

Comment: I solved it with this script

var seasons_data_url = "working-data-file.json";
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON(seasons_data_url,
    function (data) {
      var mysource = $('#sourceTemplate').html();
      var mytemplate = Handlebars.compile(mysource);
      var myresult = mytemplate(data)
      $('#resultPlaceholder').html(myresult);
  });
});

Comment: Yes you added a new table inside the first one so you have to iterate once more with an additional each loop : 
{{#each test}}
  <ul>
   <li>{{#each this}}{{#each this}}{{name}}{{/each}}{{/each}}</li>
  </ul>
 {{/each}}

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul>{{#test}}<li>{{name}}</li>{{/test}}</ul>
```

try this

Comment: this this the way to iterate in handlebar

Comment: I copied and converted an external json for a test

Comment: Isn’t there a solution? are the numbers before the objects a problem?