# Sendrid with Typescript handlebars iterations doesn't work

Tags: typescript, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I have this data, that comes form a form:

```
{
"sender": "tom_jones@test_email.com",
"portfolios": [
    {
        "id": "454453bb-8bc8-4eb1-9796-2e82046b3a12",
        "label": "Portafoglio_1"
    },
    {
        "id": "882aa086-5c3b-45e0-a76c-7f5efae6ae12",
        "label": "Portafoglio_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I am using **Sendgrid** inside Typescript file, for sending email:
using this import inside my Typescript file:

```
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
```

When it comes to use the html, **It works for the sender**, that is a simple string:

```
 <strong>${request.body?.sender}</strong>
```

but **when I have to iterate to the portfolios**, this code doesn't work:

```
   {{#each request.body?.portfolios}}
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 15px 0 0;">{{this.label}} ({{this.id}})</td>
      </tr>                                  
   {{/each}}
```

I've also tried a double for-each, like suggested in this link:
[How to iterate objects in Handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166328/how-to-iterate-objects-in-handlebars)

but it didn't work.
I tried many combinations for {{#each }} but none of them is working.

I saw many posts on Sendgrid for-each iterations, and none works.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the solution was to build the output with a piece of code nested in the html:

```
  ${request.body?.portfolios?.map((portfolio) =>
      `<tr>
         <td>${portfolio.label} (${portfolio.id}) </td>
       </tr>`
   )}
```

This is the only way that works.

The {{#each }} doesn't work.